# I can't migrate an Android project from Delphi 10.4 to Delphi 11.1

Tags: android, delphi, signature, migrate, delphi-11-alexandria

Please help if you have any idea of the following error when I try to compile my Android project completed in Delphi 10.4 after I install Delphi 11.1:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Unable to execute '"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.242.08-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -cp "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\Android\r8-3.0.73.jar" com.android.tools.r8.D8 --output "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\TestApp\Android64\Release\BarcodexMS.classes" @"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\TestApp\Android64\Release\dex_list.txt"' (Error 1)

Note: If I try to create a new application with the same name and move Forms and code from the other project with exactly the same name, it gives me an error:

> different Signature been used with the same name of the application

I have installed Delphi 10.4 again but unfortunately I get the Signature problem again. How can I get the old signature back as I have reinstalled the Windows.

By the way, I don't want to uninstall the app and reinstall again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you must revert on lib. go to Target Platform -> Android (32/64) -> Libraries. right click on mouse, then revert.

Comment: Worked just fine. Been dealing with the issue for ages, thanx.